# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build - When setting the value of a variable fetched from an API?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

I have a few json objects here -

```
{
    "error": "0",
    "message": "Got it!",
    "data": [
        {
            "status": false,
            "_id": "5e004fc92638d21e5f7e2ffc",
            "group_id": "5dfc7136790365f0955deb2b",
            "date": "2019-12-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "title": "creating new task",
            "priority": 4,
            "description": "details",
            "tasks": [],
            "created_date": "2019-12-23T05:25:29.524Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "status": false,
            "_id": "5e004ff798224784c87baff0",
            "group_id": "5dfc712d790365d5a55deb2a",
            "date": "2019-12-23T00:00:00.000Z",
            "title": "new task",
            "priority": 5,
            "description": "details",
            "tasks": [],
            "created_date": "2019-12-23T05:26:15.621Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

I am displaying the fetched data from these json objects in this method -

```
  Widget listViewWidget(List<Post> data) {
....
}
```

My application uses a `PageView` widget which displays the json objects based on the date it was created ("created_date" parameter) this way -

[image]

[image]

. I have also defined an integer `int numberOfTasksLeft;` which should hold the value of `data.length` But i need it to update everytime I am navigating to a new page (previous or next page). If there are two json objects for one day, the integer should have value of 2, etc. Could i get a suggestion on how to correctly set the value of this integer?

I have tried to use setState method this way -

```
  Widget listViewWidget(List<Post> data) {
//settervalue = data;

  setState(() {
    numberofTasks = data.length;
  });

...
}
```

but this resulted in an error - `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter just like JavaScript finishes the synchronous code first and then the asynchronous code in the next event loop. `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.`, this error occurs because even before the build finishes synchronously you are calling `setState`. So if you change the call to `setState` in an async block you solve this problem. Maybe in a hacky way though.

```
Widget listViewWidget(List<Post> data) {

  Timer(Duration(seconds: 0), () {
     setState(() {
       //settervalue = data;
       numberofTasks = data.length;
     });
  });


...
}
```

Comment: great explanation!

Comment: Welcome! This is an easy fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happened when you call setState before the widget build method is called.so make sure to setData/setState in [didChangeDependencies()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Element/didChangeDependencies.html) after widget is mounted

```
void didChangeDependencies(){


super.didChangeDependencies();
  if(mounted){
    //call setState here

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining the PageController and variables:

```
PageController controller = PageController();
var currentPageValue = 0.0;
```

Updating the variable when the PageView is `scrolled`.

```
controller.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
    currentPageValue = controller.page; or //numberofTasks = data.length;
  });
});
```