# Flutter : How To Convert Future<String> to String?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I consume API to fetch Image from database . I have response like this :

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "message": "Logo Client Is Found",
    "data": [
        {
            "fileInfo": "img-1.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want get that value from API with this code :

```
 Future<String> getLogoClient() async {
    final response = await _client.get("$_baseUrl/getLogoClient");
    final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
      List image = responseJson["data"];
      final imageList =
          image.map((json) => AppInfoModel.logoFromJson(json)).toList();
      final singleImage = imageList.single.fileInfo;
      final String urlImage = "$baseImageUrl/$singleImage";
      print(urlImage);
      return urlImage;
    } else {
      throw CustomError(responseJson["message"]);
    }
  }
```

Print response :

```
http://---/images/info/img-1.png
```

The problem is , **i want convert value from Future to String** How can i do this ?

I already trying with this code and success convert that value:

```
String urlImageApi = "";
  _getImage() async {
    final result = await appInfoApi.getLogoClient();
    setState(() {
      urlImageApi = result;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getImage();
  }
```

But I get error :

```
I/flutter ( 8408): #644    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
I/flutter ( 8408): #645    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
I/flutter ( 8408): #646    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
I/flutter ( 8408): #647    StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4381
I/flutter ( 8408): #648    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
I/flutter ( 8408): #649    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
I/flutter ( 8408): #650    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
I/flutter ( 8408): #651    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
I/flutter ( 8408): #652    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
I/flutter ( 8408): #653    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
I/flutter ( 8408): #654    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
I/flutter ( 8408): #655    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
I/flutter ( 8408): #656    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
I/flutter ( 8408): #657    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
I/flutter ( 8408): #658    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
I/flutter ( 8408): #659    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
I/flutter ( 8408): #660    StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4381
I/flutter ( 8408): #661    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
I/flutter ( 8408): #662    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
I/flutter ( 8408): #663    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
I/flutter ( 8408): #664    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4243
I/flutter ( 8408): #665    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3947
I/flutter ( 8408): #666    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4206
I/flutter ( 8408): #667    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4201
I/flutter ( 8408): #668    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3194
I/flutter ( 8408): #669    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2988
I/flutter ( 8408): #670    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1028
I/flutter ( 8408): #671    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:999
I/flutter ( 8408): #672    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:942
I/flutter ( 8408): #673    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2412
I/flutter ( 8408): #674    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:941
I/flutter ( 8408): #675    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:819
I/flutter ( 8408): #676    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:804
I/flutter ( 8408): #685    _Timer._runTimers  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:384:19)
I/flutter ( 8408): #686    _Timer._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:418:5)
I/flutter ( 8408): #687    _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage  (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
I/flutter ( 8408): (elided 11 frames from package dart:async and package dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 8408):
I/flutter ( 8408): Image provider: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter ( 8408): Image key: NetworkImage("", scale: 1.0)
I/flutter ( 8408): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I Miss Something ?

Comment: what do you mean by convert Future to String? You can't.

Comment: You need to use FutureBuilder to access string value from future.

Comment: it's possible to do without FutureBuilder ? Because properties in my widget only accept String. I success convert from Future<String> to string  with above code , app still running and success fetch image , but i get the error like above

Comment: you can. Why are you using await? If you need ui only after response then you need to use futurebuilder and future otherwise not.

Comment: you need to check empty string.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

you can use then method and can convert Future to String.

```
appInfoApi.getLogoClient().then((String result){
setState(() {
      urlImageApi = result;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason you are getting an error is because you are `await`-ing on the `initState`. Flutter expects that the code in `initState` to be non-blocking because it can't wait for `initState` to finish execution, Flutter needs to render the UI elements immediately.

You can do this by using a `then` method on a `Future` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60069480/5223309). Another way to do this is using [Timer#run](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/run.html) method like this:

```
Timer.run(() async {
    String urlImageApi = await appInfoApi.getLogoClient();
    setState(() {
      urlImageApi = result;
    });
})
```

The reason the above code works is stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59450922/5223309)

Answer (score 1):

in my case, my Future is  Future<dynamic>, I solve like this:

```
appInfoApi.getLogoClient().then((result) {
    setState(() {
       if (result is String)
            urlImageApi = result.toString(); //use toString to convert as String
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

wrap your `Image()` under a `FutureBuilder()`.

```
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: getLogoClient(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      return Image(
        image: NetworkImage('${snapshot.data}'),
      );
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Actually, this answer is a bad practice. Every time the build method is called the FutureBuilder widget will rebuild also and this make the request `getLogoClient()` triggered multiple times.